# Interaction not significant, but one simple effect significant: linear mixed model with lmer() in R

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models, interaction

**Background**: I have fit a linear mixed model using `lmer()` (`lme4` package) in R with two binary categorical predictors as dummy variables. One (*Intervention*) is within-subjects, while the other (*Sex*) is between-. The model accounts for two levels of correlation with random effects (data structure and model code described below). The outcome is proportions, but they're very well-behaved - the mean is around 0.5, with a range of about 0.2 to 0.9, and they're *very* normally distributed. Subsequently, the residuals show assumptions (normality, equal variance) are met. Thus, I don't think what I'm observing is due to violating assumptions of a linear (mixed) model.

**Issue**: The following is true no matter what random effects structure I use (which I list below): In every case, the test statistic for the interaction term between the two binary categorical predictors is about 1.7 in magnitude, while that for one of the binary predictors is always about 2.8 (the test stat for the other is ~1.3). Although there is question about how to accurately calculate *p*-values for these types of models (and whether or not we even should - I'm aware of this discussion point), it is clear that no matter the degrees of freedom used, the interaction term would be not considered statistically significant (with, say, alpha = 0.05), while the one predictor would. Note here the estimate for the individual predictor is a *simple* effect, since it is binary and dummy-coded. I used `emmeans()` to look at all four possible simple effects, and there is only one that is statistically significant (that with the test statistic of about 2.8).

I cannot figure out how the interaction could lack significance, but one of four possible simple effects *is* significant. I could see if the test statistics/*p*-values were "borderline," making it a potential issue of power. However, here the ballpark *p*-value for the interaction term (test stat ~1.7) is about 0.09, while a rough *p*-value for the simple effect (test stat ~2.8) is about 0.005. It seems problematic to me that they could differ by a magnitude, and makes me concerned that I am inherently modeling the data incorrectly, although if so, I can't see where I am in error.

**Data structure**: Each subject has an observed proportion across six different images (out of 12 possible they could have been randomly assigned): Three images were viewed pre-intervention, and three were viewed post-intervention. Thus, there is potential correlation due to subject and image, so these are considered as random effects. Lastly, *Intervention* is within-subjects, while *Sex* is between-.

Here is a small dummy dataset (not actual data, where number of unique subjects is 59 (29 of one sex, 30 of the other)):

```
structure(list(Subject = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), Image = c("B", "A", 
"G", "E", "C", "I", "C", "G", "L", "A", "D", "F", "E", "A", "K", 
"B", "C", "I", "D", "F", "H", "J", "L", "B", "D", "F", "A", "L", 
"C", "E", "J", "K", "F", "B", "A", "D"), Intervention = c("Pre", "Pre", "Pre", "Post", 
"Post", "Post", "Pre", "Pre", "Pre", "Post", "Post", "Post", "Pre", 
"Pre", "Pre", "Post", "Post", "Post", "Pre", "Pre", "Pre", 
"Post", "Post", "Post", "Pre", "Pre", "Pre", "Post", "Post", "Post", 
"Pre", "Pre", "Pre", "Post", "Post", "Post"), Sex = c("Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male"), Prop = c(0.488277, 
0.236734, 0.41036, 0.745403, 0.464705, 0.625076, 0.5602122, 0.590909, 0.333266, 0.365954, 0.374941, 0.662141, 0.64877, 0.434947, 0.721343, 0.5288113, 0.782714, 
0.603777, 0.4480342, 0.629813, 0.347684, 0.41906, 0.553854, 0.639324, 0.389804, 0.49155, 0.355763, 0.695487, 0.537433, 0.650022, 0.54022, 0.58907, 0.666208, 
0.713883, 0.625882, 0.434924)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -36L))
```

**Candidate models considered, each with varying random effects**:

**Model 1** (gave convergence warning): Note the output is that from my *actual* data (not the dummy dataset given above):

```
largest_lmer <- lmer(Prop ~ factor(Sex)*factor(Intervention) +
                            (1 | Image) +
                            (1 + Intervention | Subject), 
                     data = data01)

coef(summary(largest_lmer))
#                                            Estimate Std. Error   t value
# (Intercept)                              0.51415277 0.03503742 14.674389
# factor(Sex)Male                          0.04019813 0.03006458  1.337059
# factor(Intervention)Pre                  0.05123982 0.01830275  2.799569
# factor(Sex)Male:factor(Intervention)Pre -0.04238911 0.02509809 -1.688938

install.packages("emmeans")
library(emmeans)

largest_lmer_emm_Int <- emmeans(largest_lmer, ~ factor(Sex) | factor(Intervention))
pairs(largest_lmer_emm_Int)
# Intervention = Post:
#  contrast      estimate     SE   df t.ratio p.value
#  Female - Male -0.04020 0.0301 57.3 -1.336  0.1867 
# 
# Intervention = Pre:
#  contrast      estimate     SE   df t.ratio p.value
#  Female - Male  0.00219 0.0307 57.2  0.071  0.9434 
# 
# Degrees-of-freedom method: kenward-roger

largest_lmer_emm_Sex <- emmeans(largest_lmer, ~ factor(Intervention) | factor(Sex))
pairs(largest_lmer_emm_Sex)
# Sex = Female:
#  contrast   estimate     SE   df t.ratio p.value
#  Post - Pre -0.05124 0.0184 56.5 -2.789  0.0072 **This is the significant simple effect**
# 
# Sex = Male:
#  contrast   estimate     SE   df t.ratio p.value
#  Post - Pre -0.00885 0.0172 55.0 -0.515  0.6084 
# 
# Degrees-of-freedom method: kenward-roger
```

**Model 2**: All output similar to that from Model 1 (not repeated here):

```
medium_lmer <- lmer(Prop ~ factor(Sex)*factor(Intervention) + 
                           (1 | Image) +
                           (1 | Subject) +
                           (1 | Intervention:Subject), 
                    data = data01)
```

**Model 3**: All output similar to that from Model 1 (not repeated here):

```
smallest_lmer <- lmer(Prop ~ factor(Sex)*factor(Intervention) + 
                             (1 | Image) +
                             (1 | Subject), 
                      data = data01)
```

As I mentioned, *all* of these candidate models gave roughly the test statistics noted above - they did not vary depending on the random effects included. Assumptions of the model (normality, equal variance) were met. Is there something else I'm missing? Or is it mathematically possible to have an insignificant interaction, but a significant simple effect *that differ as much as these two do* with regard to their test statistic/*p*-value?

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but just a comment. When you specify your model as "Prop ~ factor(Sex) * factor(Intervention) ...", R converts your Sex and Intervention variables to numbers. Sex becomes: 1 = Female, 2 = Male. Intervention becomes: 1 = Post, 2 = Pre. Then, when you multiply them, you get the following numbers: (a) Male/Pre = 4, (b) Male/Post = 2, (c) Female/Pre = 2, and (d) Female/Post = 1. Here, (b) and (c) have the same values (i.e., 2), but they are actually different; (b) is Male/Post and (c) is Female/Pre. Is this really what you want?

Comment: Actually, I am not sure about my previous comment, but I think it is worth checking.

Comment: @Haci Duru. Putting factor() around a variable uses dummy coding - 0/1, not 1/2.

Comment: So, here is what I see when I factor one of your variables. `fSex <- factor(data01$Sex)` `fSex` `[1] Female Female Female Female Female Female Female Female Female Female Female Female Female Female Female Female Female Female Male   Male   Male  
[22] Male   Male   Male   Male   Male   Male   Male   Male   Male   Male   Male   Male   Male   Male   Male  
Levels: Female Male` `as.numeric(fSex)` `[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2`

Comment: Hi, you might be on the wrong site to get an adequate answer, since that's more a statistical question. I recommend paste the question to [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and delete it here. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, @jay.sf - I never know the best site to post on, but it seems Cross Validated gets less traffic, so if I'm unsure, I usually post here.

Comment: 1/3 @Haci Duru When you convert a factor to a numeric variable (`as.numeric(fSex)`), R always starts at 1. This is different than wrapping a variable in `factor()` in a regression model, where it chooses one level as reference (baseline), and compares all other factor levels to this (the definition of dummy coding), despite how the factor variable is coded (with letters, numbers, etc.).

Comment: 2/3 You can see the current levels of baseline by running your code above, followed by `contrasts(fSex)`. Then, to further check it's really using 0/1, you can recode and refit, comparing to the model that used `factor()` around `Sex` and `Intervention`: `data01$Sex_01 <- ifelse(data01$Sex=="Female", 0, 1)` and `data01$Intervention_01 <- ifelse(data01$Intervention=="Post", 0, 1)`, then `largest_lmer_01 <- lmer(Prop ~ Sex_01*Intervention_01 + (1 | Image) + (1 + Intervention | Subject), data = data01)`, e.g. (note this model gives a warning about singularity).

Comment: 3/3 This is the only text I have with me right now that explains it: Discrete Data Analysis with R (Friendly, Meyer): The dataset being discussed has `Sex` and `Treatment` already as factor variables (pg. 39). Then, when fitting a model with these as predictors on pg. 273, it says, “Using the default (0/1) dummy coding that R uses (“treatment” contrasts against the lowest factor level)…” Also, this sort of indirectly discusses it, but doesn’t call it “dummy coding,” but does talk about a reference group: http://tutorials.iq.harvard.edu/R/Rstatistics/Rstatistics.html

Comment: Note you use `summary()` with the appropriate model name in parentheses (`largest_lmer_01`, e.g.) after running each model to get the output.

Comment: I agree that this belongs on CrossValidated (but it will probably get migrated there soon).  The most useful information you could give us would be the output of `coef(summary(m))` where `m` is one of the fitted models.  Possibly output of `emmeans` too ...

Comment: Added for Model 1 (other two follow similarly).